# Java - Reg. Ex. File Question

Tags: java, regex

I'm grabbing lines from a text file and sifting line by line using regular expressions. I'm trying to search for blank lines, meaning nothing or just whitespace.

However, what exactly is empty space? I know that whitespace is \s but what is a line that is nothing at all? null (\0)? newline (\n)?

I tried the test harness in the Java tutorial to try and test to see what an empty space is but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty string `""` is a string. It's not `null`. It doesn't have any character, not even `\0` (which is just a character in Java, i.e. it's not a string terminator ([JLS 10.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.9))).

The following are all true:

```
"" != null
"" instanceof String
"".contains("")
```

The following are true *exclusively for an empty string*:

```
"".matches("")
"".matches("^$")
"".length() == 0
"".isEmpty()
```

This is also true for an empty string as well as all other strings containing only whitespaces:

```
"".matches("\\s*");
```

This is because `*` is zero-or-more repetition of a pattern. Zero repetition of a whitespace is an empty string.

The following is also true for all strings containing only whitespaces:

```
s.trim().isEmpty()
```

---

#### Further discussions

> I notiched that `\s*` detects one or more whitespaces. How do I make it so that it detects only whitespace? For example `"test test"` would be invalid?

`\s*` matches *zero* or more whitespaces, and `"test test".matches("\\s*")` is `false`.

*However*, you *can* `find` `\s*` in `"test test"`, just as you can find it *in any string*, because `\s*` can match the empty string, and all strings `contains("")`.

> Figured it out... `^\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9\W]|^$`

`[^a-zA-Z0-9\W]` doesn't really make any sense, and in fact `"_".matches("^\\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9\\W]|^$")`.

Perhaps the confusion is because `matches` in Java needs to match the *whole string* (i.e. as if you've surrounded the entire pattern with `^` and `$`), so you can drop the anchors for `matches` but you'd need it for, say `find`. The proper regex for such methods would then be `"^\\s*$"`, with the anchors explicitly included.

The following is an excerpt from cletus's original answer (which is now deleted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileString);
while (m.find()) {
  ...
}
```

The `Pattern.MULTILINE` allows `^` and `$` to also match line terminators within `fileString`.

Comment: I notiched that \s* detects one or more whitespaces. How do I make it so that it detects only whitespace? For example "test    test" would be invalid?

Comment: Figured it out...^\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9\W]|^$

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) -class. It has nice `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` methods that handle also nulls nicely:

```
Checks if a String is empty ("") or null.

 StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

.

```
Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

 StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
 StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```